# Custom list labels in ConTeXt

Tags: lists, context

I have just started learning ConTeXt and I have to say that I am pretty amazed by how intuitive it is to use. But I can't find a way yet to achieve automatically a list with the following labels.

```
C.1
C.2
C.3
.
.
.
```

What I have come up with so far is with the use of `\sym`:

```
\starttext
\startitemize[packed]
\sym{C.1} Three coins are tossed. In how many ways can at least 2 heads turn up?
\sym{C.2} If $\log_x 8^{1/2}=3/4$, what is $x$?
\sym{C.3} If $x:y=10:21$ and $y:z=28:9$, what is $x:y:z$?
\stopitemize
\stoptext
```

In LaTeX, with the `enumitem` package, it is easy to achieve this with the following minimal code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={C.\arabic*}]
\item ...
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way that I can automate the list in ConTeXt? I tried some of the ConTeXt manuals but all I have seen up to now are just the predefined lists. I also tried looking for a duplicate in this site using the `[context]` tag but I have been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: Nice to see yet another brave ConTeXt user!  ConTeXt is really a great system, much better than LaTeX in many respects (but having its limitations, too).  Did you see this: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/User-Defined_Enumerations ?

Comment: @mbork Thanks for the link. I am really getting out of my comfort zone here. But I am afraid using the strategy in the link, I have to manually specify the labels myself. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the command `\setupitemgroup` to configure how the itemize lists
are being displayed. See [ConTeXt wiki - setupitemgroup](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupitemgroup) for more information.

```
\setupitemgroup
  [itemize]
  [packed, n]

\setupitemgroup
  [itemize]
  [distance=2ex,
   left=C.,
   stopper=]

\starttext
\startitemize
  \startitem Three coins are tossed.                 \stopitem
  \startitem If \math{\log_x 8^{1/2}=3/4}            \stopitem
  \startitem If \math{x:y=10:21} and \math{y:z=28:9} \stopitem
\stopitemize
\stoptext
```

The `n` setting changes the bullet to a number, the `left` key controls what
is printed at the left of the enumeration and removing the `stopper` gets rid
of the dot which is used by default for numbered items.

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks Marco! I did see `\setitemgroup` and was already doing some experiments with it. I saw the `left` option but had no I idea what it does until I saw it in your answer. In the ConTeXt wiki for instance, it was just described as `text`. Thanks again!

Comment: If you want to do this for a one off list, you can also use `\startitemize[n][left=C.]`

Comment: @Aditya That simple? Okay, yeah. it was a one off list. Thanks. That was really helpful.